# fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: command-line, ssh, ram

I am frequently getting:

```
fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

when running commands over `ssh`. I have 4 GB of RAM and usually 2 GB free. This started happening since I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10.

I then need to repeatably run the command until it finishes successfully.

I'm connecting from my laptop to my server both from my home LAN. Some times happens even when I run apt-get.

Any idea why?

Comment: I think you have to provide more details otherwise this won't be solveable. I suppose the machine you are describing is the ssh server you are connecting to? (and not the client)  When this happens run `free` and post the output here (and what program caused the error)

Comment: Are you running in a VPS ?

Comment: I'm connecting from my laptop to my server both in home lan. Some times happens even when I run apt-get. I'll check free next time.

Comment: I am getting exactly same problem, also lots of others.

See this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11649751

Comment: How much memory is bash using when it happens? `ps -o rss,vsize,args $$`

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide us with the output of `ulimit -a` ran in a session where this happens?

`/etc/pam.d/sshd` should involve `pam_limits.so` when you open a session. This module will use `/etc/security/limits.conf` to apply various restrictions to your session, including regarding memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when attempting to run `top` while my swap partition was not active (0 swap memory) and it was resolved by enabling swap on `/dev/sda5`:

```
swapon /dev/sda5
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. You could improve your answer by including an example command to enable swap. From [review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/779349).